# Não consigo importar tabelas com require

Tags: lua

Eu estou aprendendo a programação Lua, e estou aprendendo o Require. Mas quando vou tentar importar uma tabela ou qualquer outra coisa que for acontece um erro.

O que eu estou tentando fazer é exportar uma tabela com uma função.

O que eu quero exportar:

```
  local calculadora = {
    somar = function(x, y)
        return x + y
    end
}

function calculadora.multiplicar(x, y)
    return x * y
end
```

Como estou importando:

```
require("calculadora")

print (calculadora.somar(1, 1))
```

O erro:

```
lua: segundo.lua:1: module 'calculadora' not found:
    no field package.preload['calculadora']
    no file '.\calculadora.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\calculadora.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\calculadora\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\calculadora.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\calculadora\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\calculadora.luac'
    no file '.\calculadora.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\calculadora.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\loadall.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\calculadora.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\loadall.dll'
    no file '.\calculadora51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\calculadora51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\calculadora51.dll'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    segundo.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
>Exit code: 1
```

O que faço?

Comment: A mensagem de erro é clara: Lua não achou o arquivo `calculadora.lua` em nenhum dos lugares listados.

Answer (score 2):

Você acabou esquecendo de exportar a tabela calculadora.

Segue o exemplo:

```
local calculadora = {
    somar = function(x, y)
        return x + y
    end
}

function calculadora.multiplicar(x, y)
    return x * y
end

return calculadora
```

Agora no arquivo que você vai importar, você deve atribuir o require a uma variável para poder fazer a chamada.

```
local calculadora = require("calculadora")

print(calculadora.somar(1, 1))
```

[Modules and Packages](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/%7Eroberto/pil2/chapter15.pdf)

Ver exemplo na página 11 do arquivo pdf no item "Listing 15.2"